# How to create a raw ERC-4337 UserOperation from scratch and then send it to bundler?

Tags: mocha, erc, erc-4337, account-abstraction

I want to create a raw ERC-4337 UserOperation. I am using ethers library to write the test cases .

According to ERC-4337 official documentation , the UserOperation is a struct with many fields .

Reference : https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337#definitions

How to calculate each fields value ( like initCode , calldata , signature etc ) and combine them to make a UserOperation struct which will then be sent to the alternative mempool ? [ Edit : I searched through repos and got something , dont know if it's correct ]
Below is the test case I wrote to create a UserOperation and send it to bundler ( I have StackUp's bundler url )

```
it("creating a user operation from scratch and then send it to bundler", async function () {
const EntryPoint_Addr = "0x5FF137D4b0FDCD49DcA30c7CF57E578a026d2789";
const RECEIVER_ADDR = "0x53C242Cc21d129155aCC5FAc321abDfe83C35Af7"; // sending ether to this address
const amount = '1000000000000000'; // amount to send to RECEIVER_ADDR

const sender = "0x1e87a1Eca600313aE1388D04e71ea473AD468CAE"; // smart account address , created by calling createAccount method of AccountFactory ( deployed at 0x9406Cc6185a346906296840746125a0E44976454 ) passing RECEIVER_ADDRESS as address and 1 as salt value
const nonce = '1'; // used salt's value as 1 at the time of smart account creation . that's why I kept it same .
const callGasLimit = '500000';
const verificationGasLimit = '200000';
const preVerificationGas = '50000';
const maxFeePerGas = '1000000000'; // adjust the value according to your needs
const maxPriorityFeePerGas = '100000000'; // adjust the value according to your needs
const account = new ethers.utils.Interface(accountABI); // ethers code
const calldata = account.encodeFunctionData('execute',[RECEIVER_ADDR, amount, "0x"]);
// calldata : 0xb61d27f600000000000000000000000053c242cc21d129155acc5fac321abdfe83c35af700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038d7ea4c6800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    
// getUserOpHash function is taken from StackUp's UserOp library . Reference : https://github.com/stackup-wallet/userop.js/blob/main/src/context.ts
const getUserOpHash = () => {
            const packed = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
              [
                "address",
                "uint256",
                "bytes32",
                "bytes32",
                "uint256",
                "uint256",
                "uint256",
                "uint256",
                "uint256",
                "bytes32",
              ],
              [
                sender,
                nonce,
                ethers.utils.keccak256('0x'),             ethers.utils.keccak256('0xb61d27f600000000000000000000000053c242cc21d129155acc5fac321abdfe83c35af700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038d7ea4c6800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'),
                callGasLimit,
                verificationGasLimit,
                preVerificationGas,
                maxFeePerGas,
                maxPriorityFeePerGas,
                ethers.utils.keccak256('0x'),
              ]
            );
        
            const enc = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
              ["bytes32", "address", "uint256"],
              [ethers.utils.keccak256(packed), EntryPoint_Addr, 80001]
            );
        
            return ethers.utils.keccak256(enc);
         }

         const userOpHash = getUserOpHash();
        //  userOpHash value : 0x1a23a91638f4a6c594c64b1b17bb930f9505c244b7a9cbc7065213bfccc71ba9

        // Arraified the userOpHash . Reference : https://github.com/stackup-wallet/userop.js/blob/main/src/preset/middleware/signature.ts
        
        const arraifiedHash =  ethers.utils.arrayify(userOpHash);
        console.log("arraified Hash :",arraifiedHash);
        const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://polygon-mumbai.infura.io/v3/infurakey"); 
        const wallet = new ethers.Wallet('myprivatekey', provider);
        const signer = wallet.provider.getSigner(wallet.address);
        const serializeObj = JSON.stringify(arraifiedHash);   // **error suspect 1**
        const signature = signer.signMessage(serializeObj);

        const options = {
          method: "POST",
          url: "https://api.stackup.sh/v1/node/stackupkey",
          headers: {
            accept: "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
          data: {
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            id: 1,
            method: "eth_sendUserOperation",
            params: [
              {
                sender: "0x1e87a1Eca600313aE1388D04e71ea473AD468CAE",
                nonce: "0x0",
                initCode: '0x',
                callData: "0xb61d27f600000000000000000000000053c242cc21d129155acc5fac321abdfe83c35af700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038d7ea4c6800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                callGasLimit: "500000",
                verificationGasLimit: "200000",
                preVerificationGas: "50000",
                maxFeePerGas: "1000000000",
                maxPriorityFeePerGas: "100000000",
                paymasterAndData: "0x",
                signature:signature
              },
              "0x5FF137D4b0FDCD49DcA30c7CF57E578a026d2789",
            ],
          },
        }; 
        await axios
          .request(options)
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Some information to understand `UserOptions` and to create them.

1. You should know your ERC4337 infrastructure

   - EntryPoint - a contract to get your `UserOperation` and handle it
   - Account - your erc4337 contract account (*like multisig*)
   - Account Factory - a contract that creates that Account for you

There will be many account abstraction implementations. Below, we'll look into `https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction`, which StackUp also uses, to prepare raw `UserOperation`.

2. Prepare the ERC4337 account initialization data via Account Factory

Here we generate the **`initCode`** and calculate **`initCodeGas`**.

[SimpleAccountFactory.sol](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/blob/d1333cf58c17d5cc84e830f3fc3a69081c777979/contracts/samples/SimpleAccountFactory.sol#L28)

Create the transaction data for the `createAccount` method of the `AccountFactory` and prepend the AccountFactory address so that the `EntryPoint` contract can create the account during the handling of the `UserOperation`.

It will look like this:

```typescript
let createAccountTx = await accountFactoryContract.$data().createAccount({ address: owner }, owner, salt);
let initCode = $abiUtils.encodePacked(['address', 'bytes'], [ accountFactoryContract.address, createAccountTx.data ]);
let initCodeGas = await this.client.getGasEstimation(entryPointContract.address, createAccountTx);
```

3. Calculate **ERC4337 account address**

To make it simple, we'll use on-chain method [EntryPoint.sol::getSenderAddress](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/blob/d1333cf58c17d5cc84e830f3fc3a69081c777979/contracts/core/EntryPoint.sol#L356) to get the erc4337 account address based on `initCode`

As this is the `WRITE` method which reverts with the address, we simply `call` it and get the sender.

```typescript
let { error, result } = await this.entryPointContract.$call().getSenderAddress({ address: owner }, initCode);
let erc4337AccountAddress = error.data.params.sender;
```

3. Prepare Target contract transaction data

Here we generate the **`callData`** and calculate **`callDataGas`** for our arbitrary contract transactions as we would do for normal transactions.

4. Get the **`nonce`**

The `EntryPoint` contract has the method `getNonce(address sender, uint192 key)` - so, we can use it:

```typescript
let nonce = await entryPointContract.getNonce(erc4337AccountAddress, 0);
```

5. Prepare **`maxFeePerGas`** and **`maxPriorityFeePerGas`**.  You can leave these values empty, then the EOA who sends the transaction to the entry point is paying for this UserOperation. Otherwise, you can retrieve the current gas price and set the values as you do it for a normal transaction. But your Erc4337 account must be pre-funded with ETH, or you use Paymasters.

---

What we have so far:

```typescript
let op: Partial<UserOperation> = {
    sender: erc4337AccountAddress,
    initCode: initCode,
    callData: callData,
    callGasLimit: BigInt(callDataGas),
    verificationGasLimit: 150000n + BigInt(initCodeGas),
    nonce: nonce,
    maxFeePerGas: 0n,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: 0n,
}
```

- We use the min value for `verificationGasLimit` required by the entrypoint
- If the erc4337 Account was already previously deployed, you won't need any `initCode` and `initCodeGas`

---

6. Get the **`opHash`** (Operation Hash)

The `EntryPoint` contract has the method `getUserOpHash(UserOperation calldata userOp)` - so, we can use it:

```typescript
let opHash = await entryPointContract.getUserOpHash(op)
```

7. Get the **`signature`** by signing the `opHash` with the owner's private key (eip-712):

```typescript
let sig = await signEIPHashed(opHash, owner);
let opSigned = {
    ...op,
    signature: sig.signature
};
```

> The steps above may be different depending on ERC4337 implementation and web3 library, but the key points remain.

Finally, your UserOperation (`opSigned`) is ready to be submitted to the blockchain by you, your friend, or Bundler.

You can get additional information from tests

- https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/blob/d1333cf58c17d5cc84e830f3fc3a69081c777979/test/UserOp.ts#L128
- https://github.com/0xweb-org/dequanto/blob/0e59297ddefea670136ca2ce3f11f98d6efc5bbe/test/erc4337/erc4337.spec.ts#L34

Comment: Great post. Just a question, which owner's private key here at step 7.? 7. Get the signature by signing the opHash with the owner's private key (eip-712): If AA could eliminate seed phrases / private keys for end users, is there still a private key required to sign txs?

Answer (score 0):

So , this is how I was able to send a UserOperation.

```
it("creating a user operation from scratch and then send it to bundler", async function () {
         const sender = "0x0Dc570f9aD08D370dCa4D097A9f1b1E477Cb79A2"; // smart account address
         const nonce = '0'; 
         const callGasLimit = '500000';
         const verificationGasLimit = '200000';
         const preVerificationGas = '50000';
         const maxFeePerGas = '1000000000'; 
         const maxPriorityFeePerGas = '100000000';
         const account = new ethers.utils.Interface(accountABI); 
         const amount = '1000000000000000'; // amount to send to RECEIVER_ADDR

         const calldata = account.encodeFunctionData('execute',[RECEIVER_ADDR, amount, "0x"]);
         console.log("calldata :", calldata);
         // 0xb61d27f600000000000000000000000053c242cc21d129155acc5fac321abdfe83c35af700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038d7ea4c6800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

         const getUserOpHash = () => {
            const packed = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
              [
                "address",
                "uint256",
                "bytes32",
                "bytes32",
                "uint256",
                "uint256",
                "uint256",
                "uint256",
                "uint256",
                "bytes32",
              ],
              [
                sender,
                nonce,
                ethers.utils.keccak256('0x'), // initCode is kept 0x because I called createAccount method of Smart Wallet Factory before sending the user operation , if the smart account is not onchain we have to calculate initCode 
                ethers.utils.keccak256(calldata),
                callGasLimit,
                verificationGasLimit,
                preVerificationGas,
                maxFeePerGas,
                maxPriorityFeePerGas,
                ethers.utils.keccak256('0x'),
              ]
            );
        
            const enc = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
              ["bytes32", "address", "uint256"],
              [ethers.utils.keccak256(packed), EntryPoint_Addr, '80001']
            );
        
            return ethers.utils.keccak256(enc);
         }

         const userOpHash = getUserOpHash();
         console.log("userOpHash :",userOpHash);
        //  0xcd11aba8b720ebb64a7d7359fd6af0d9b7977095b921a094b8a745ce520f6888

        const arraifiedHash =  ethers.utils.arrayify(userOpHash);
        // console.log("arraified Hash :",arraifiedHash);
        const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://polygon-mumbai.infura.io/ws/v3/key"); // Connect to the Matic mainnet (replace with your desired network)
        const signer = new ethers.Wallet('privatekey',provider);
        const signature = await signer.signMessage(arraifiedHash);
        // console.log("signature :",signature);
        // 0x39770a3658efac589f5b3fcbf0292061bddae46d88d6c4e3ff1412d1a037b0a633cfda59a27ad7a48d39a8af7d5a5ee8bf6904e294fa354b1c42f7f71727839f1c
        const options = {
          method: "POST",
          url: "https://api.stackup.sh/v1/node/093e60e352135a8b93ba198c8e62138868eb9bfca0147ff9e00da75b267e2b0c",
          headers: {
            accept: "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
          data: {
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            id: 1,
            method: "eth_sendUserOperation",
            params: [
              {
                sender: "0x0Dc570f9aD08D370dCa4D097A9f1b1E477Cb79A2",
                nonce: "0x0",
                initCode: '0x',
                callData: "0xb61d27f600000000000000000000000053c242cc21d129155acc5fac321abdfe83c35af700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038d7ea4c6800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                callGasLimit: "500000",
                verificationGasLimit: "200000",
                preVerificationGas: "50000",
                maxFeePerGas: "1000000000",
                maxPriorityFeePerGas: "100000000",
                paymasterAndData: "0x",
                signature:signature
              },
              "0x5FF137D4b0FDCD49DcA30c7CF57E578a026d2789",
            ],
          },
        }; 
        await axios
          .request(options)
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });
    });
```